# What is `except*` syntax in Python? (TryStar in ast module)

Tags: python, exception, syntax

I came across [this documentation in the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.TryStar) for a version of the `try`/`except` block with an extra asterisk. The documentation doesn't explain what it is, and gives a completely generic example:

> ### `class ast.TryStar(body, handlers, orelse, finalbody)`
>
> `try` blocks which are followed by `except*` clauses. The attributes are the same as for Try but the ExceptHandler nodes in handlers are interpreted as except* blocks rather then except.
>
> ```py
> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("""
> try:
>    ...
> except* Exception:
>    ...
> """), indent=4))
> ```

What is `except*` and what is it for? Is it deprecated, or up-and-coming?

(And perhaps more importantly, what is the feature called? except-star? except-glob? except-asterisk? try-star?)

Comment: It's for Exception Groups and it's one of the feature introduced in Python 3.11

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-pep654) is the relevant part of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`except*`(aka except-star) is one of the feature/syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except-star) introduced in Python 3.11 and it is used to handle [`ExceptionGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ExceptionGroup). Quoting from the official documentation

> `except*` clause
>
> The `except*` clause(s) are used for handling `ExceptionGroups`. The exception type for matching is interpreted as in
> the case of except, but in the case of exception groups we can have
> partial matches when the type matches some of the exceptions in the
> group. This means that multiple `except*` clauses can execute, each
> handling part of the exception group. Each clause executes at most
> once and handles an exception group of all matching exceptions. Each
> exception in the group is handled by at most one `except*` clause, the
> first that matches it.
>
> ```
> try:
>     raise ExceptionGroup("eg",
>         [ValueError(1), TypeError(2), OSError(3), OSError(4)])
> except* TypeError as e:
>     print(f'caught {type(e)} with nested {e.exceptions}')
> except* OSError as e:
>     print(f'caught {type(e)} with nested {e.exceptions}')
>
> # caught <class 'ExceptionGroup'> with nested (TypeError(2),)
> # caught <class 'ExceptionGroup'> with nested (OSError(3), OSError(4))
> #   + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
> #   |   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
> #   | ExceptionGroup: eg
> #   +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
> #     | ValueError: 1
> #     +------------------------------------
> ```